# UpdatePanel, update a lable on master page and previous pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an "AddItem" button which adds an item to the shopping cart. Everything works fine, but the label witch displays the number if items in the shopping cart does not get updated, unless i refresh the page. I have tried many things, but nothing seemed to be working. I have two questions, how can i update the label, and how to update it on the previous pages as well? For example, when user click the back button the lable should display the updated value.

Master page

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
         <span class="myBag"> My Bag (<asp:Label id="numItems" runat="server"></asp:Label>)
         </span>
 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Master page, code behind

```
    int numItems = cartAccess.numItemsInCart();
    Label numItem = (Label)this.FindControl("numItems");
    numItem.Text = numItems.ToString();
```

Adding page

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateItem" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="addToCart" CssClass="addToCart"  Text="Add to Shopping Bag" runat="server"/>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Adding page, code behind

```
private void adding(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext();
    string  itemid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    string quntity = "1";
    CartAccess test = new CartAccess();
    test.add(itemid, quntity);
    ContentPlaceHolder pl = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
    UpdatePanel up = (UpdatePanel)pl.FindControl("UpdatePanel1");
    AsyncPostBackTrigger tr = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
    tr.ControlID = ((Control)sender).ID;
    tr.EventName = "Click";
    up.Triggers.Add(tr);

    Label numDisplay = (Label)pl.FindControl("numItems");
    int numItem = (from item in context.ShoppingCarts select item).Count();
    numDisplay.Text = numItem.ToString();




}
```

Answer (score 0):

try add

> AutoPostBack="true"

```
<asp:Label id="numItems" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server"></asp:Label>

<asp:Button ID="addToCart" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="addToCart"  Text="Add to Shopping Bag" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Nope, still does not get updated. It does get updated on the adding page when i remove all the code starting from "ContentPlaceHolder pl" and click a couple of times on the button.